# How do you manage ASP.NET MVC users, after deployment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do you manage(CRUD) users in aspnet_db after you deploy your site?

Do you just create models for them after merging the aspnet_db database into your sites database?

And then create admin views to edit and manage them?

Comment: You will need to define *manage* and *user* before this question becomes answerable.

Comment: How do I create, edit, update, delete users in the aspnet_db that get's generated for you. I know how to merge this data into my sites database, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you want to allow users to be managed through a web interface on your site, then yes you need to create models, controllers and views. In this case you are using the built-in [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx) to create, update and delete users. If you don't need a web interface you could always remotely connect and administer the SQL database.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Good kit available from
[The ASP.NET MVC membership starter kit](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks that looks like a great starting point. I wonder how compatible it is with MVC2, since it was built for MVC 1.0.